# PowerApps Line chart, select vlaue from dropdown box to display the values

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I'm trying to create a chart in Powerapps to display what computers I have per category, selected from a dropdown box. The data is from a sharepoint list, and I'm battling to get the correct data to show in the dropdown box (ie: In Stock, Repairs, Stock Room etc.) so that I can display in a chart what items are in that category (ie: iMac 27", Macbook Pro 13" etc.). I'm pulling my hairs out and would appreciate any assistance. All these options are, in Sharepoint, selected from a list to avoid adding new categories due to typos.

I hope I've explained this properly.

[Data source example - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGqh2.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. From Power Apps studio, go to `View` / `Data Sources` and connect to the Sharepoint list.
2. Once connected to the list, set the dropdown `Items` property to the name of `YOUR_SHAREPOINT_LIST`.
3. With the dropdown selected, look on the right properties pane for the `Value` dropdown and select the Sharepoint list column you want to display in the dropdown

[image]

Ideally, you would never connect a dropdown (or combobox or Gallery, etc) *directly* to a Sharepoint list. You should create a collection first then connect the control to the collection instead.

**Example:**

- `OnVisible` of the screen where data will be used:

```
ClearCollect(colDdPicklist, 
    YOUR_SHAREPOINT_LIST
)
```

- Then set the dropdown `Items` property to `colDdPicklist` and select the column to display.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. The issue I'm experiencing is that the sharepoint list column I want to select is not showing up in the Value dropdown for the Item. The sharepoint list column is called Status, which is a "choice" type column which does not show up in Value dropdown for the list.

Comment: Go to the Sharepoint list. Click the `Gear Icon` / `List Settings` then click the "Status" column. Look in the URL for `...field=`. This is the internal name of the column. Should say `...field=Status` unless you changed the name of the column.

Comment: ...Field=Model, this is a handy thing to note! Model or Status are still not showing up in the list, the only field column that isn't showing up.

Comment: Glad that helped. Yeah, I never use Choice-type columns because they always require special handling. I'd suggest eliminating the `Model` column in Sharepoint and create a new `Status` column of type `Single line of text`. Then control which choices are available using PowerApps. Ex: `Items` : `["Thing1", "Thing2", "Thing3", "etc."]`

Comment: Thanks so much for your guidance. I've added new columns, and it has done the trick! Legend!